# BizTalk Server Application Project fails to compile with .NET 4.7.2

Tags: azure-devops, biztalk, .net-4.7.2, biztalk-2020

In my newly created BizTalk 2020 Dev environment when I'm adding a BizTalk Server Application Project (.btaproj) to the solution, the dialog window where you set the name of the project is showing the .NET framework selector and it defaults to version 4.7.2 as expected.

However when the project is added to the solution I can see in the properties for the project that it is targeting .NET 4.6.1. Has anyone seen this? is it a bug or something wrong with installation?

Naturally I change it to version 4.7.2 as the regular BizTalk project and everything compiles fine in Visual Studio.

But on our build server the same project fails. We use Azure Devops for CICD.On the build server we have the same version of VS installed (2019 enterprise) and BizTalk Server Extention (v3.12.1.0) is installed as well as msbuild tools from BizTalk server installation.

In the logs I first get a Warning:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3274: The primary reference "A.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1". [B.btaproj]*

And further down in the log the btaproj will not find the assemblies to include in the .zip package.

Message above implies that I have different target versions but I don't.

Now the strange thing is that I can log on to the build server and clone the same project and compile it with VS just fine.

The only way to make the build server compile the project successfully (or any other BizTalk project with .btaproj for that matter) is to change .NET to 4.6.1 (for both .btproj and .btaproj) and it all compiles nicely and deploys to BizTalk environment.

I have checked project files and files checked in to Git and everything seems OK with the sources files. The clean flag I set to clean sources and output directory. I Can compile a regular BizTalk project and .NET application with 4.7.2 on build server just fine it's only when I involve a .btaproj project where it starts to misbehave.

Can anyone point out where to start to look? the .btaproj seems fishy to begin with but it can also be isolated to the msbuild on build server and it differs from compiling with Visual Studio.

Comment: You can try to re-specify v4.7.2 to overwrite the previous version,just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2JTF.png).

Comment: Thanks, turns out that i failed to set the correct framework version moniker for release on the .btaproj, why it defaults to 4.6.1 to begin with is strange. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the BizTalk Server Application project e.g .btaproj defaults to target framework moniker 4.6.1 when added to the solution you will need to manually change the version manually for BOTH debug and release.

Do not get misled by the create project dialog where it defaults to version 4.7.2 
[image: project dialog]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround ,you can specify `/p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.7.2` in the MSBuild Arguments column of the MSBuild task.

[image]

MSBuild lets you set properties on the command line by using the -property (or -p) switch. These global property values override property values that are set in the project file. This includes environment properties, but does not include reserved properties, which cannot be changed.

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties).

Comment: It is the Target framework moniker that needs to be set for the project .btaproj, in this case i failed to also change the release settings and it defaulted to 4.6.1 even though i selected 4.7.2 when adding the project. Thanks for your help!